# Add a query-time variable in sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am compiling a raw statement where I need to assign previous query result to a variable and use it as an id for the next query. Unfortunately I don't remember how to do it in SQL.

This is what I get

```
01-18 18:22:22.443: E/AndroidRuntime(5801): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id,date,title,description, (SELECT title FROM discipline WHERE _id=gdid ) AS discipline_title FROM alert WHERE _id=(SELECT eaid FROM alert_to_discipline) AS gdid
```

I suspect that AS gdid is a wrong way to make it a variable. How do I do it?

Here is more-nicely formatted query

```
SELECT _id,date,title,description,
    (SELECT title FROM discipline WHERE _id=gdid ) AS discipline_title
        FROM alert WHERE _id=(SELECT eaid FROM alert_to_discipline) AS gdid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this experience too. You can't use temporary variables in SQLite. The best way is just to run a query and assign it to a java declared variable. Then pass it in for the second query.